# Ps4 controller not recognized in Device Manager

Tags: windows-10, drivers, game-controller

I've played with my ps4 controller for a while on pc but suddenly it doesnt work anymore. I suspect it's from last windows update but I can't say for sure.
Ds4 windows won't recognize my device, I tried installing drivers with SCPToolkit but my controller doesn't show on "Select dualshock 4 to install" just my mouse, keyboard and headset.

On the device manager I can't see any HID controller or general wireless controller. By plugging and unplugging my device in different usb ports on my MOBO I managed to get a "setting up wireless controller device" and got the light of the controller start flashing, but after a few seconds it just died again.

I'll post some pics of my device manager and SCPToolkit to make you understand better the situation.

[image: Universal Serial bus controllers]

[image: HID]

[image: SCPT1]

[image: SCPT2]

P.S. I forgot to mention the controller works on the PS4 and the usb cables I tried (about 4) work on phone to charge and transfer file.

P.S#2 I even tried with PS4 remote play, the controller works to remotely operate the ps4, but as soon as I close the remote play and open up DS4Windows it goes blank again.

Comment: Try uninstalling the DS4 tool and reinstall latest version..https://ds4tool.com/

Comment: Tried of course and didn't work

Comment: The problem is that I should be having it in the HID even if ds4 drivers weren't installed correctly. It's like I'm connecting a dead device to my pc, I get no response from the device manager either

Comment: Yes I'm having this issue as well. The yellow charging indicator comes on but it simply does not show as a device on the PC. I've tried the original cable, numerous other cables I own, each USB port available on my PC, nothing.